# Linq Query to fetch the the grand child

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to fetch the grand child using linq but no success so far. The structure of data is something like below

```
    public class GrandParent 
{ 
    public int grandkey; 
    public List<GrandParent> parent { get; set; } 
}
public class Parent
{
    public int parentkey;
    public List<Child> child { get; set; }
}
public class Child
{
    public int childkey { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

I have grandparent object. using linq I want to fetch the child value. I know I can do it in two line but I want to get it something in one line

something like this `var a = from hh in parent where hh.child.Select(c=>c.Value)`

Comment: This doesn't make sense, please try again (with an edit). What is your expected output?

Comment: The Q in LINQ stands for query. A query doesn't change things, so how is it supposed to delete something? Furthermore, your code shows a simple select. How is that supposed to delete something?

Comment: Here I am trying to get all the child.value!=0 value

Comment: Do you want to delete all child records where `child.value!=0`?

Comment: I just want child record with non 0 values either by using select linq or by deleteing them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the following classes:

```
public class Parent
{
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public string Key { get; set; }

    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

And the following setup:

```
var parents = new List<Parent>
{
    new Parent
    {
        Children = new List<Child>
        {
            new Child { Key = "KEY1", Value = 5 },
            new Child { Key = "KEY2", Value = 0 },
            new Child { Key = "KEY3", Value = 1 },
            new Child { Key = "KEY4", Value = 0 }
        }
    },
    new Parent
    {
        Children = new List<Child>
        {
            new Child { Key = "KEY5", Value = 0 },
            new Child { Key = "KEY6", Value = 0 },
            new Child { Key = "KEY7", Value = 1 },
            new Child { Key = "KEY8", Value = 0 }
        }
    }
};
```

You could remove all of the items with Value == 0 with:

```
parents.ForEach(p => { p.Children.RemoveAll(c => c.Value == 0); });
```

That would leave you with 2 children in the first parent object and 1 child in the second parent object.

I hope this helps.